# Unresolved reference: SentryFlutter

Tags: android, flutter, sentry

The project stopped running on Android with error:

```
e: file:///../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/sentry_flutter-7.16.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/sentry/flutter/SentryFlutterPlugin.kt:39:39 Unresolved reference: SentryFlutter
    
e: file:///../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/sentry_flutter-7.16.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/sentry/flutter/SentryFlutterPlugin.kt:49:21 Unresolved reference: SentryFlutter
```

This error for android occurs both when running from Flutter and when running from Android. iOs app running successfully.

Withal, I have found this [issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/issues/1857) on github with the same error. Tried some advices from there and from [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/issues/1857) but no success. any help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just had the same issue after upgrading from Sentry `7.10.1` to `7.16.0`, fixed the problem with

`flutter clean`